# GoogleSheets - Calculate XIRR from different sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-finance

I have two sheets: `Portfolio` and `Transactions`.

My transaction sheet looks like this :

[image]

My portfolio sheet looks like :

[image]

Here total Market rate refers the current market price of total X stocks.Say, I have a total of 44 HDFCBK stocks, so 44 * current market price (Rs.1659.9) is 73,035.6.

I would need to display the XIRR of each stock in my portfolio sheet from transactions sheet.

Any help how this can be done?

Thanks.

Comment: do you have a "selling" sheet?

Comment: Nope. XIRR needs to be calculated based on today's date anyday.

Comment: right, i know the XIRR function, i'm asking if you ever anticipate having any sales of positions at all?  There does not seem to be any in the sample data?

Comment: XIRR needs to be calculated based on the assumption that I am going to sell that stock in today's rate

Comment: i understand that. i'm saying it also is calculated by taking into account any prior sales of *part* of the position. I don't see any examples of that in your data